# SQL Server 2016 CTP 2, FOR JSON AUTO generates multiple lines of JSON text

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I'm playing with the JSON feature with SQL Server. I'm using a 2016 CTP 2 version of SQL Server. My test code is:

```
select db_name(database_id) db_name, name, physical_name
from sys.master_files
for json auto
```

The result I got is:

```
JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
-----------------------------------------
[{"db_name":"master","name":"master","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\master.mdf"},{"db_name":"master","name":"mastlog","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\mastlog.ldf"},{"db_name":"tempdb","name":"tempdev","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\tempdb.mdf"},{"db_name":"tempdb","name":"templog","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\templog.ldf"},{"db_name":"model","name":"modeldev","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\model.mdf"},{"db_name":"model","name":"modellog","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\modellog.ldf"},{"db_name":"msdb","name":"MSDBData","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\MSDBData.mdf"},{"db_name":"msdb","name":"MSDBLog","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\MSDBLog.ldf"},{"db_name":"ReportServer","name":"ReportServer","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\ReportServer.mdf"},{"db_name":"ReportServer","name":"ReportServer_log","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\ReportServer_log.ldf"},{"db_name":"ReportServerTempDB","name":"ReportServerTempDB","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\ReportServerTempDB.mdf"},{"db_name":"ReportServerTempDB","name":"ReportServerTempDB_log","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\ReportServerTempDB_log.ldf"},{"db_name":"RServices","name":"RServices","physical_name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\RServices.mdf"},{"db_name":"RServices","name":"RServices_log","physical_
name":"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\RServices_log.ldf"}]
```

Note that under the header the JSON text has been split into two lines. Why this? If I can a two line result, three or more lines is also possible as I understand. How to get a consistent result?

Comment: Just curious.  If you change Results to Text (Cntrl-T) is your JSON still wrapping?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, yes, still wrapping in text result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest SQL Server RTM or at least some CTP3 version. JSON formatting in SSMS is changed in January release (3.3) and now it returns entire JSON text as one continuous line in new window (similar to FOR XML).
In Visual Studio/SSDT you can nicely format JSON output.